# UITableView Header View Width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uistoryboard

I'm trying to customize the width of my headerview on a UITableVIew. Unfortunately no matter what parameters  I give it in the setframe method it always seems to have a width that is same as the tableview. I couldn't find an answer that talked about this, most answers seemed to talk about the section headers as opposed to the talbeviewheaders. Can anyone tell me of a way to customize the width of a tableview header?

Edit:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
   UIImageView *myImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage     imageNamed:@"takephoto.png"]];
  [myImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100)];
 [[self myTable]setTableHeaderView:myImage;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you're currently doing?

Answer (score 2):

Add `myImage` as the child of another view. The containing view will be automatically resized but you can then configure `myImage` to be the size you require.